# Swift 3 iterate over a nested Dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, loops

Okay, so, swift noob alert:

How do I do the simplest of iterations given the following array (I dont know what to call this shape: array, dictionary, object...)?

```
func showNotification(_ sender: [AnyHashable: Any]) { ... }
```

> sender["actions"]:
>
> Optional([{"text":"Confirm","type":"response"},{"text":"Decline","type":"response"},{"link":"https://www.stackoverflow.com","text":"Website","type":"info"}])

attempts:

```
if let result = sender["actions"] {
  print("YES \(result)")
  for action in result as! [String] {
    print(action)
  }
}
```

`the above prints`:

```
YES [{"text":"Confirm","type":"response"},{"text":"Decline","type":"response"},{"link":"https:\/\/www.stackoverflow.com","text":"Website","type":"info"}]
```

...however, returns the following error:

`Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1a7c28d50) to 'NSArray' (0x1a7c297c8)`

The end goal here is to simply get to each one of the actions individually, ie:

`{"text":"Confirm","type":"response"}`

`{"text":"Decline","type":"response"`

ect...

Does Swift have a `map` function...  FYI Im coming in from a Java and JavaScript world...  `swiftyjson` seems a bit heavy for one loop.

Thanks, and as always any help and direction is appreciated!

**edit:**

This is the print via the param passed to the function `sender`:

```
sender: [AnyHashable("title"): title!, AnyHashable("message"): message, AnyHashable("message_id"): 0:1503511875428318%03300c3203300c32, AnyHashable("id"): 1497708240713, AnyHashable("actions"): [{"text":"Confirm","type":"response"},{"text":"Decline","type":"response"},{"link":"https:\/\/www.notifyd.com","text":"Website","type":"info"}], AnyHashable("aps"): {
    "content-available" = 1;
}]
```

Comment: Swift does have map

Comment: This question is confusing. Please clearly show the output of `print("YES \(result)")`.

Comment: No, I am still unable to loop through the nested Dictionary.  The `Does Swift have a map function` was a suggestion to an alternative, not the question.

Comment: Look in the question I posted that print result.  right after `I get to the YES:`

Comment: The error implies that `result` is actually a `String` which is why you can't cast it to an array. But the output you claim is from the `print` indicates that `result` is an array of dictionary. This is why I asked you clarify the output of the `print`.

Comment: @rmaddy understood, and that is the actual print to xcode console listed above.

Comment: No, it's not the actual print because your `print` statement includes the text `YES `. Please [edit] your question with the exact, actual output of the `print` statement into your question.

Comment: It looks to me like sender["actions"] contains a JSON string, not [[String:String]]. JSON decoding needs to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to decode the JSON String and then cast to an array of Dictionary:

```
if
    // cast sender["actions"] to String
    let actionsString = sender["actions"] as? String,
    // decode data of string and then cast to Array<Dictionary<String, String>>
    let actionsStringData = actionsString.data(using: .utf8),
    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: actionsStringData, options: []) as? [[String : String]] 
{

    print("YES \(result)")

    for action in result {
        print(action)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do `if let` twice.

Comment: `if let result = sender["actions"] as? [[String : String]]`

Comment: This seems correct (finally) except it doesn't explain the error message. The  supposed output in the question implies this answer would be correct but the error message indicates that `result` is actually a `String`, not an array of dictionary. The question seems contradictory.

Comment: @dj-tech42 Thanks for the snippet, unfortunately, using this does not hit "YES" so nothing is printed.  What can I post that will help resolve this?  I hear contradictory and confusing but those adjectives dont lead me to a better solution, and are not helpful otherwise.

Comment: The issue is that `sender["actions"]` is actually a json string that hasn't been decoded so the type is actually `String`. Once it is decoded, it will have the type `[[String : String]]` and you can cast it this way, but without decoding, this cast will fail and the code inside the `if` block will not run.

Comment: @DjTech42 perhaps you should add JSON decode to your answer.

Comment: @DjTech42 I appreciate the feedback but Im not sure how to decode the JSON string, is that the same as parsing?

Comment: I edited my answer to include JSON decoding before the cast

Comment: @DjTech42 Thanks!  unable to compile with: `Value of type 'Any' has no member 'data'`

Comment: Added the print from the function param, if that sheds any light into the issue...

Comment: I fixed the compilation error, the issue was that it wasn't casting `Any` to `String` first

Comment: `let result = try? JSONSerialization ...` . ...with a slight mod, this works as expected.   Thanks for the efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Is it really true that what you've got here is an undecoded JSON string? In that case, Swift 4 makes this really easy:

```
struct S : Decodable {
    let link : String?
    let text : String
    let type : String
}

if let acts = sender["actions"] as? String {
    let data = acts.data(using: .utf8)!
    if let arr = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Array<S>.self, from: data) {
        arr.forEach {print($0)}
    }
}

/*
S(link: nil, text: "Confirm", type: "response")
S(link: nil, text: "Decline", type: "response")
S(link: Optional("https://www.stackoverflow.com"), text: "Website", type: "info")
*/
```

Comment: That looks much cleaner than the alternative.  Unfortunately this is a react-native app and I dont believe the native modules portion (swift) will be supported above 3 (I havent actually researched that as fact though).

Answer (score 0):

There is something fishy going on here with the data. Let's treat the data with more care. Here is a method to get JSON from a JSON object, a JSON array, a Data object or a string.

```
enum JsonError: Error { case notJson; case notJsonArray }

func json(from any: Any?) throws -> Any {
    if let json = any as? [String: Any] { return json }
    if let json = any as? [Any] { return json }

    if let data = any as? Data {
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
    }

    if let string = any as? String, let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
    }

    throw JsonError.notJson
}
```

Now that I'm being more careful with the JSON object, I should get the what I want or know more about the error.

```
func showNotification(_ sender: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    do {
        guard let result = try json(from: sender["actions"]) as? [Any] else {
            throw JsonError.notJsonArray
        }

        print("YES \(result)")

        for action in result {
            print("Action: \(action)")
        }
    } catch {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```